# Scope for Personal macro library

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro saved in my personal.xlsb .
The first step of this macro determines the number of sheets in the current workbook using

```
Dim NumSheets As Integer
NumSheets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
```

I invoke this macro from any number of workbooks with many different numbers of sheets but the value is always being assigned as 1. My best guess is that in the Personal.xlsb workbook, there is only one sheet. How would I be able to have it get the current number of sheets in whatever workbook I am invoking the macro from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThisWorkBook` object refers to the workbook that the code is contained in. However the `ActiveWorkBook` object refers to the workbook that is currently active.
In your case since the workbook running the code is not the active workbook, using `ActiveWorkBook` will fix your issue and point to the current workbook as you want it to do.

Comment: Well, seeing it now, that was painfully simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `ThisWorkbook`, use `ActiveWorkbook`.

Or you can use `Workbooks("A_Workbook")`, where "A_Workbook" is the name of a specific workbook. You would pass the name of the workbook as a `String` parameter into your macro.

To clarify both approaches:

#### 1. If using `ActiveWorkbook`:

```
Public Function NumSheets() As Long

  NumSheets = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

End Function
```

#### 2. If using `Workbooks("...")`:

```
Public Function NumSheets(wbName As String) As Long

  NumSheets = Workbooks(wbName).Worksheets.Count

End Function
```

Note that your macro must be `Public` so that it can be accessed by other workbooks.